# Angularjs directive, maintaining internal state for each of the directive instance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has dependency on a service, I am maintaining some directive state in the service.
So whenever same directive is used in two places, it needs to instantiate the new service.
for example,

```
<body>
 First directive instance: <custom-directive> 1 </custom-directive>
 Second directive instance: <custom-directive> 2 </custom-directive> 
</body>
```

In this case, both the controllers are populated with the same service object, but I need the different service objects to maintain their states internally.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a service/factory, but expose a `getInstance` method inside your service that returns a new instance, allowing you to inject and subsequently create a new instance for each directive.

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('sharedService', sharedService);

function sharedService() {
    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            return new instance();
        }
    }

    function instance() {
        // functionality
    }
}
```